# Docker container with centos 6.6 and c++

Tags: docker, centos-6, g++

I'm trying to create a docker contaienr with CentOS 6.6 and c++:

```
Step 1/37 : FROM centos:6.6
 ---> 3d7ac13b921a
Step 2/37 : RUN yum -y update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b41e216c79de
Step 3/37 : RUN yum -y install yum-plugin-ovl centos-release-scl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a77e2870e01b
Step 4/37 : RUN yum -y install epel-release
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95a1f9a75059
Step 5/37 : RUN yum -y install cmake3 devtoolset-4-gcc* hwloc-devel libmicrohttpd-devel openssl-devel make git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 087a467c925c
Step 6/37 : RUN scl enable devtoolset-4 bash
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e98843aeb7f
Step 7/37 : RUN echo $PATH
 ---> Running in de0e7d3bd428
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Removing intermediate container de0e7d3bd428
 ---> e7a900636a88
Step 8/37 : RUN c++ --version
 ---> Running in c51c9901049c
/bin/sh: c++: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c c++ --version' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

but i get

```
/bin/sh: c++: command not found
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post the results of: echo $PATH
The commands that you used should have done this, but just to be sure, verify that the /opt/tools/rh/devtools-4/root/usr/bin has been added to your path.

Comment: It seem the C++ compiler itself is missing. Try to add first `RUN yum install gcc gcc-c++`.

Comment: hm when installing gcc and gcc-c++ before devtoolset-4-gcc* i have a c++, but only the old version 4.4 instead of 5.3

Comment: the new compiler seems to be here '/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/bin/c++', but why is it not on path?

Comment: @NasirRiley $PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: hm `RUN source scl_source enable devtoolset-4; c++` seems to work

Comment: You don't need to have gcc=c++ installed if the devtools are installed. Wutzebaer, you should now see the directory /opt/tools/rh/devtools-4/root/usr/bin in your path. You can either add it with your code or by manually adding it via your .bash_profile